# verify code authy with restsharp

Tags: c#, twilio, authy

I use the next piece of code to ask for a code to for a 2fa (two factor authentication) and works well:

```
private async void TwilioSMS(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification");

        RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("start", RestSharp.Method.POST);
        numcheck = Numero.Text.Trim();
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
        string este = "{\"api_key\":\"" + apikey + "\",\"via\":\"sms\"," + "\"country_code\":52," + "\"phone_number\":"+numcheck + ",\"locale\":\"es\"}";

    request.AddParameter("text/json", este, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
        RestSharp.IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

        respuesta = response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(respuesta);
}
```

But when I try to make the verification with the next piece of code:

```
private async void VerifCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (numcheck == string.Empty) { numcheck = Numero.Text.Trim(); }

            RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification");

                RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("check", RestSharp.Method.GET);

                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;


            string este = "{\"api_key\":\"" + apikey + "\",\"country_code\":52," + "\"phone_number\":" + numcheck + ",\"verification_code\":" + Confirmation.Text.Trim() + "}";

            request.AddParameter("text/json", este, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
                RestSharp.IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

                respuesta = response.Content;
            Console.WriteLine(numcheck);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

                var listo = respuesta.Split(new string[] { "\"success\":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                if (listo.Contains("true"))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Código correcto", "El código es correcto", "OK");
                }

                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Código incorrecto", "El código es incorrecto o no ha sido mandado", "OK");
                }
        }

        catch { await DisplayAlert("Código incorrecto", "El código es incorrecto o no ha sido mandado", "OK"); }


    }
```

I get the next error:

```
{"error_code":"60001","message":"Invalid API key","errors":{"message":"Invalid API key"},"success":false}
```

I use the same api key for both, why the error happens?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When making a call to `api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/check` the request should be a `GET` request. You have made a `GET` request, however you passed the parameters as JSON in the body of the request. When making a `GET` request you do not pass a body, so the Authy API is not reading them. The parameters should be included as query string parameters in the URL and your API key should be set in the `X-Authy-API-Key` header. See [the curl example here for more detail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#example_1).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I already figured it out, but I forgot to put it here.